# While statement without expression

Tags: python, if-statement

Here is a part of a code in Python I try to figure out what it is doing:

`while index < len(list) and list[index]: index += 1`

I wonder what the part after the "and" (`and list[index]`) does exactly? I tried to add "is True" or "is False" but both did not yield the same result, so it does not check for True or False I guess.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: The `if` statement in python succeeds not only on `True` but on several other conditions. E.g. `if 1: print('ok')` even though `1 is True` returns `False`. Thus the statement in `list[index]` checks for any of the various true statements which is the negative of what is false, namely `0`,`False`, or `None` (did I miss anyone?).

Comment: Check [Truthy and Falsy Values in Python](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/truthy-and-falsy-values-in-python/) for discussion of Truthy and Falsy values and their use in while loops and conditionals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It checks for a *Truthy* value, i.e., a value that does not evaluate to `False`. Falsy values might include, for example, `None`, `0`, `False` etc. In a nutshell, the *while* loop stops at the first Falsy value.
For a list of Falsy values, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39984051/14375203).

Answer (score 0):

"While index value is greater than length of list (index < len(list)) and index value of list is present (list[index]) increment index value by 1."

Example:

```
list = [1, 2, "three", 333, 30.54, "asdasx"]
index = 0

while index < len(list) and list[index]: 
    print(len(list), list[index])
    index += 1
```

at 1st iteration list[index] value is 1 
at 2nd iteration list[index] value is 2 
at 3rd iteration list[index] value is "three" and so on... 
until the value for the list[index] is not null it will remain **'True'** thus the program will execute.